# Silverlight UI lag - Crosshair on Graph

Tags: c#, silverlight, performance

I've got a telerik radchart that's displaying a beautiful and incredibly-useful-to-end-user line chart.

One of the requirements for this chart was to have a x-value crosshair on the graph (e.g. when a user hovers at any point over the graph, a horizontal line appears, and where this line intersects the actual graph line, a value is displayed in another area of the screen).

In a previous iteration, I used flotJS to do my graphing & crosshair'ing, worked great, and was blazing fast. In converting this to silverlight, I've seen a tremendous amount of lag, and I'd like to know if anyone has any ideas on improving performance.

I currently expose the chart's MouseEnter/MouseLeave events to hide/show the horizontal line. This is done via a System.Windows.Visibility property sitting in my viewmodel (which my crosshair's visibility property is bound to). I then use the MouseMove method to actually calculate the x position.

Here is the code that runs this (first in my chart view's code behind)

```
private void rad_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var plotAreaPanel = this.rad.DefaultView.ChartArea.ChildrenOfType<ClipPanel>().FirstOrDefault();
    var position = e.GetPosition(plotAreaPanel);

    var x = rad.DefaultView.ChartArea.AxisX.ConvertPhysicalUnitsToData(position.X);
    (this.DataContext as ViewModels.DateCountsViewModel).XVolume = x;
}

private void rad_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (this.DataContext as ViewModels.DateCountsViewModel).XVolumeVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

private void rad_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (this.DataContext as ViewModels.DateCountsViewModel).XVolumeVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Then in my viewmodel, in the setter for XVolume (which is being Set in the MouseMove method above), this code:

```
    public double XVolume
    {
        get { return xVolume; }
        set
        {
            this.xVolume = value;
            decimal currentX = (decimal)Math.Round(value, 0);
            var vol = this.VolumeCollection.Where(x => x.XValue == currentX).FirstOrDefault() as Models.ChartModel;
            this.Volume = (vol == null) ? 0 : (int)vol.YValue;
            RaisePropertyChanged("XVolume");
        }
    }
```

With heavy usage, the line lags up to several inches behind my pointer. I tried throttling my mouse events [outlined here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/06/throttling-silverlight-mouse-events-to-keep-the-ui-responsive/), but it's still really laggy.

[Note regarding link above: It uses the CompositionTarget.Rendering event, which is fired just before a frame is rendered. Therefore, to throttle the effect of the mouse event, we set a flag to indicate that we are waiting for a change to be rendered, then reset this flag just before rendering occurs... not allowing simultaneous rendering]

What can I do to mitigate this lag?